# How do you stop Sparx Enterprise Architect adding relationships to all diagrams?

Tags: enterprise-architect

When I add a relationship between two elements in a diagram (in this case a communication diagram) in Sparx EA it adds it to every diagram that has those two elements. This means I have to go back and remove it from every other diagram that has those two elements, a task that gets harder the more diagrams you have.

Is there a way to stop this happening?

Comment: You should really stop and think why this is a problem. If the two elements are in fact related, why is it a problem then that the relation shows up in diagrams that show both elements? Wouldn't you want that? I'm guessing you are doing something wrong here. Possibly you only want to model a relationship between two instances of the elements, and not the elements themselves. In that case you should use objects, and classifiers.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the distinction is between the instances and the element itself. In a communication diagram for a solution aren't they the same thing?

Comment: Richard, they are never the same thing. The element or **Classifier** describes the general class of the thing, the instance describe an object of that class. For example the class `Human` describes the characteristics humans have such as height, name, hair-color, gender. In **instance** of such Human could describe me. With name = Geert, Gender = Male, Height = 1.80m, etc.. Usually when describing relations of instances you don't want to see them on any other diagrams. Relations between classes should always be visible when those two classes are used on a diagram.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that idea in terms of classes but in terms of physical systems (in this case various systems involved in identity management) I'm not sure what the distinction is in Sparx. Wouldn't everything be an instance? And so what would the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going to discuss the meaning of what you are trying but you can select the connector after creation and from the context menu use `Visibility/Hide in other diagrams`.

You can also write an add-in that can do that automatically for you. In that case you need to subscribe to `EAOnPostNewConnector`.